# Binding a click event to a frame below a label

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a frame with three labels in it, and I would like to click anywhere in the frame to trigger an event. Unfortunately, the labels are on top of the frame and the clicks aren't registering.

```
frame=tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
frame.bind("<1>", function)

L1=tk.Label(frame, text="Label_1")
L1.pack()
L2=tk.Label(frame, text="Label_2")
L2.pack()
L3=tk.Label(frame, text="Label_3")
L3.pack()
```

Do I need to bind the click event to each label?

**Edit for clarity**: I have a frame with three labels in it. I have it this way because it's the only way I could format the three strings properly (just one Label object doesn't allow much for formatting individual parts). I would like to click anywhere in the frame to trigger an event, i.e. click any of the labels, anywhere, and have the same event triggered. Right now I can see three solutions:

1. I find a way to click through the labels to click the frame
2. I find a way to format the three Labels as one Label. I don't think it's possible to format a Label like a printf though.
3. I bind the same command to each Label.

Potential 4th solution: I create a Frame that inherits from a Button. Not sure if this is possible either. Maybe I can add multiple Labels to a Button?

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Try `Canvas` instead of `Frame`, `Canvas` should allow `.bind('<1>'` and has the ability to layout multiple "Text" items using [Canvas.create_text-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_text-method)

Comment: @stovfl Using a `Canvas` worked perfectly, thank you!